# QUIC client api to send packets to server (To test my server api)

Tags: c, client, quic

I am a newbie. I have created a basic server.c to implement quic using ngtcp2 library. I want to check whether my server receives data or not. Is there any api like postman to send packet from client-side for quic protocol.

Or is there any quic client, that I can directly use to check my server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have query on my code. I just want to know if there is any "quic client api/code (open source) available" to test my server code.

Answer (score 0):

ngtcp2 has an [example HTTP/3 client](https://github.com/ngtcp2/ngtcp2/blob/main/examples/client.cc) that you can use.

Comment: Thanks!. I have used that and made connection with my server. But, I think this example client is not sending data (If I am wrong, pls correct me). So, If there is any other client where I can check sending data to my server, would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[picoquic: Minimal implementation of the QUIC protocol](https://github.com/private-octopus/picoquic)